# how to adjust/stretch image size on form resize pyqt4 python

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlabel

i have a qlabel with an image, it is inside a QGridLayout.
when the form re-sizes the QGridlayout automatically resize but the qlabel with image does not stretch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting [scaledContents](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qlabel.html#scaledContents-prop) property to True?